# Values of $a,b,c,d,e$ such that the sequence $f(n)=\frac{a g(n-1,n)+b g(n,n+1)}{c g(n-1,n)+d g(n,n+1)+ e}$ is nonincreasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, problem-solving

Let $\mathbb N$ be the set of naturals, and let $g:\mathbb N\times \mathbb N \to [0,\infty)$ be a function. Define, for all natural numbers, $$f(n)=\frac{a g(n-1,n)+b g(n,n+1)}{c g(n-1,n)+d g(n,n+1)+ e}$$ For what positive real numbers $a, b, c, d, e$ is the sequence $\{f(n)\}$ non-increasing?

---

So I need to prove that for all $n=1,2,3...$, $f(n)\geq f(n+1)$.

For a special case $a=b=c=d=e=1$, we see $\{f(n)\}$ nonincreasing.

I am trying to evaluate $f(n)-f(n+1)\geq 0$ on paper, but unable to to do the next step.

Can we consider this function $$f(x)=\frac{a g(x-1,x)+b g(x,x+1)}{c g(x-1,x)+d g(x,x+1)+ e}$$ and determine the values of parameters for which $f'(x)\leq 0$? Derivative is given [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative+of+f%28x%29%3D%5Cfrac%7Ba+g%28x-1%2Cx%29%2Bb+g%28x%2Cx%2B1%29%7D%7Bc+g%28x-1%2Cx%29%2Bd+g%28x%2Cx%2B1%29%2B+e%7D)

Comment: I removed the tags `metric-space` and `convergence` since they were not accurate

Comment: In your question you say nothing about the function $g.$ Is that intentional, meaning $g$ can be *any* function at all and you want your $f$ to be nondecreasing?

Comment: oops meant "you want to show $f$ is nonincreasing"

Comment: @coffeemath Yeah I imagine if $g(x,y) = e^{x^y}$ that we're going to have some problems no matter what... OTOH, looking at it, if $a=b=c=d$, $f(x) = q/(q+e)$, which shouldn't increase? I think?

Comment: Though if $g(a,b)$ has any periodic component or anything weird, the answer here might be "never." OP, do we have *any* info about $g$?

Comment: No, the only condition for $g$ is $g\geq 0$. However, I understand your point, it might not be possible in general. What about if we take $a=c,b=d$ so we have $f(x)=\frac{q+1}{q+1+r}, q=\frac{a}{b}, r=\frac{e}{b}$. This will be non-increasing right?